# html element goes outside the table column

Tags: html, css

I have an html table with 2 rows and 3 columns.

I am putting another table inside the 2nd column of 2nd row of 1st table, but the second table goes outside the boundary of 1st table. I'm confused.

Comment: please, copy and paste your code into [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Show your code so far, if you want us to help.

Comment: please share http://jsfiddle.net/ link!

Answer (score 0):

Share your code or check your sequence

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1st row and 1st column</td>
  <td>1st row and 2nd column</td>
  <td>1st row and 3rd column</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2nd row and 1st column</td>
  <td>                   <!-- you want insert Table here -->  
    <table>
    <tr><td>nested table</td></tr>
    <tr><td>nested table</td></tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td>2nd row and 3rd column</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

more information visit [here](http://www.pageresource.com/html/table3.htm)